# Infinite discounted sum of weakly dependent Normal random variables

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, summation, normal-distribution

Say I have the expected value of a sum of weakly dependent Normal random variables of the form $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n X_n\right]$, where $0<a<1$. I was wondering under what conditions this sum might converge and what the expectation then is?

I believe that the sum in the expectation converges absolutely by monotone and dominated convergence if something like $\sup_n \mathbb{E}|X_n|=M<\infty$ holds true (when would this hold for our $X_n$?).

In summary, do you have an idea about under what conditions such a sum converges, and why? Or could you point me at useful references?

Comment: @ kelu : Could you please be more precise about the notion of "weakly dependency" that your normal random variables satisfy. Best regards

Comment: What I meant is that it is short-range dependent. Let's say it is an ARMA process.

Comment: But this is more a research question, so anything related is interesting to me. So if you have a good idea that requires something slightly different, that's also much appreciated!